# C++ alternative to public members

Tags: c++, class, private, public

Consider this example

```
class Sprite    
{
public:
    Sprite(int imageID, int maskID);
    ~Sprite();
    //some methods
}

Sprite::Sprite(int imageID,int maskID)
{
    //this is the class for creating sprites in winapi..its doesnt matter what it has in this example
}

Sprite::~Sprite()
{
    DeleteObject ( mhImage );
    DeleteObject ( mhMask );
}

class Car{
public:
    enum Type{
        Ferrari,
        BWM
    };
    Car(Type type);
    ~Car();
    void InitSpeed()
    void ChangeSpeed();
    //..some methods
private:
    Sprite *car;
}
```

and its implementation

```
Car::Car(Type type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
    case Ferrari:
        car=new Sprite("Ferrari","FerrariMask");
        break;
    case BMW:
        car=new Sprite("BMW","BMWMask");
        break;
    }
}

void Car::InitSpeed()
{
    speed=100;
}

void Car::ChangeSpeed()
{
    speed=200;
}

Car::~Car()
{
    delete car;
}

class BuildCar:public Car
{
public:
    BuildCar();
    ~BuildCar();
    Car*BMW;
    Car*Ferrari;
}

BuildCar::BuildCar()
{
    Ferrari=new Car(Ferrari);
    BMW=new Car(BMV)
}

BuildCar::BuildCar()
{
    delete Ferrari
    delete BMW;
}
```

and in may main class I will have:

```
#include "Car"

class Game
{
private:
    //etc
    BuildCar*mycars;

    //etc;
}

Game::Game()
{
    mycars=new BuildCar();
    mycars->BMW->InitSpeed();
    mycars=>Ferrari->InitSpeed();

    ....
    at some point i will have:
    mycars->BMW->ChangeSpeed();
    mycars->Ferrari->ChangeSpeed();
}
```

If I make `Car*BMW` and `Car*Ferrari` private members of `BuildCar`, the whole program won't work because I can't access private members of class `BuildCar`.

I can make them private and in `BuildCars`. I will add some setters and getters so that I can access them, but what if I have many pointers to car? I will have to make many setters and getters in `BuildCar` for example:

```
Car*GetBMW()
{
    return BMW
}

Car*GetFerrari()
{
    return Ferrari;
}
```

And now in my main class it will work

```
mycars->GetBMW()->ChangeSpeed();
mycars->GetFerrari()->ChangeSpeed();
```

I know its a bad practice to make class members public but how is it in my example? And what can be done?

Comment: None of those pointers look necessary at all.

Comment: But then how can i access from main class the class Car if in BuildCar i dont have a pointer to class Car unless in my main class i have Car*mycar instead of BuildCar*mycar?

Comment: Can't you cut down your example code a bit more? I think it's quite hard to understand. In any case, it *sounds* like you need a `friend` declaration somewhere. Make the members private and grant `friend` access to whoever needs them. This avoids otherwise unnecessary getters and setters.

Comment: The class name `BuildCar` sounds like a design flaw. Some class are functors, but this one is not. Non-functor classes are generally not *doers*.

Comment: Well,i tried to make BuildCars a class in which i create the objects otherwise i should create them in my main class which will became bigger in time.

Comment: You just have objects. `Car c; c.ChangeSpeed();` Voila. If you actually need a pointer for, say, polymorphism, use a smart pointer. If you need to pass them in such a way that others can modify them, you do so by reference (or by pointer, but without `new`). Right now, you're not following the Rule of Three/Five. Your classes will break easily because of that. By the way, "`BuildCar` is a `Car`" makes no sense, so it shouldn't inherit at the very least. It doesn't even use the inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question, but the design could be a little better. Instead of having a single `Car` class that handles multiple types of car, have one base `Car` class, and have the other car types inherit from that class.

Then the `CarBuilder` class is a so-called [factory class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_class) which distinguish between the different types of cars, but return a `Car` instance to you.

Something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Car
{
public:
    Car() : speed(0) {}
    virtual ~Car() {}

    void setSpeed(int speed) { this->speed = speed; }
    int getSpeed() const { return speed; }

    virtual std::string getType() = 0;

private:
    int speed;
};

struct Ferrari : public Car
{
    std::string getType() { return "Ferrari"; }
};

class BMW : public Car
{
    std::string getType() { return "BMW"; }
};

class CarBuilder
{
public:
    enum CarType
    {
        Ferrari,
        BMW
    };

    static std::unique_ptr<Car> makeCar(const CarType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case Ferrari:
            return std::unique_ptr<Car>(new ::Ferrari);
        case BMW:
            return std::unique_ptr<Car>(new ::BMW);
        default:
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto myCar = CarBuilder::getCar(CarBuilder::Ferrari);
    std::cout << "My car is a " << myCar->getType() << '\n';
}
```

The above program will print

```
My car is a Ferrari
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you predefine a situation in which `mycars` object contains Ferrari and BMW cars only - your code is absolutely fine. You can for example:

```
Car* bmw = mycars->getBMW();
Car* ferrari = mycars->getFerrari();

bmw->ChangeSpeed();
// etc.
```

But consider that you have ten cars. In that case an `std::vector<Car*>` might be a better choice, although you would refer to the cars by their numerical ID.

The bottomline is that there are lots and lots of ways to write what you want in a proper C++ (which is a mirage :). You can write with or without pointers, with smart pointers or references, maps, vectors, arrays and so on. As long as you learn C++ - just do it the best way as you know it.